# Girsanov theorem with stochastic drift

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I am trying to solve the following exercise from Lawler's lecture notes on Stochastic Calculus.

> Suppose $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion on $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$.
> For each of the following choices of $X_t$, $0 \le t \le 1$, state
> whether there is an equivalent probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ such
> that the $X_t$ is a standard Brownian motion in the new measure. If
> the answer is yes, give $d\mathbb{Q}/d\mathbb{P}$ at $t = 1$. In all
> cases assume that $W_0 = 0, X_0 = 0$.
> $$ \begin{array} dX_t &= 2 dt +
>  dW_t ,\\ dX_t &= 2 dt + 6 dW_t , \\ dX_t &= 2W_t dt + dW_t . \end{array} $$

I would start this exercise by repeating the usual sketch of proof for Girsanov's theorem.
Let $X_t$ be a solution of:
$$
dX_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t)dW_t.
$$
Define the stochastic process $M_t$ on $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ as:
$$
M_t = \exp\left(-\int_0^t \mu(s,X_s)d W_s - \frac12 \int_0^t \mu(s, X_s)^2 ds\right).
$$
It is not hard to check that $M_t$ fulfills:
$$
dM_t = -\mu(t,X_t)M_tdW_t.
$$
Introducing a new stochastic process $Y_t = M_t X_t$, we have
$$
dY_t = \mu_t(1-\sigma_t)M_t dt + (\sigma_t - \mu_t X_t)M_t dW_t,
$$
therefore if we introduce a new measure $d\mathbb{Q} = M_t d\mathbb{P}$, the representation of $X_t$ in this new measure is
$$
dX_t^{\mathbb{Q}} = \mu_t(1 - \sigma_t)dt + (\sigma_t - \mu_t X_t^{\mathbb{Q}})d W_t^{\mathbb{Q}}.
$$
It follows that there exists a change of measure where the stochastic process $S_t$ is a standard Brownian motion iff $\sigma_t$ is identically 1 (this is the only way to make the drift term disappear).

If I carry out explicitly the computation for the third stochastic process in the exercise's text, I get (here I replace the constant 2 with a symbolic constant $\mu$):
$$
dY_t = (1 - \mu W_t X_t)M_t dW_t,
$$
where the Brownian motion $W_t$ is referred to the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.
I find it hard to rewrite the equation above as an equation for the original process $X_t$ in the new measure $\mathbb{Q}$.
My natural guess would be:
$$
dX_t^{\mathbb{Q}} = (M_t - \mu W_t^{\mathbb{P}}X_t^{\mathbb{Q}}) dW_t^{\mathbb{Q}},
$$
but I don't like it because there is a Brownian motion with respect to $\mathbb{P}$.
My question is: is the equation above correct? Should I just accept the fact that this the equation of a driftless Brownian motion with respect to $\mathbb{Q}$, even if the diffusion is a not very clear stochastic process?

I suspect the problem here is that $M_t$ is not a martingale, as the expectation of $\int W_s dW_s$ is $O(t)$, but I do not see clearly how this ruined the last result: it seems the drift term disappeared anyway.